# Mongoose find and sort using multiple fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema for a document in MongoDB:

```
var postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  domain: { type: String, enum: ['public', 'private'], required: true },
  created_at: { type: Date },
  last_modified: { type: Date },
  data: {
    start_date: {
      year: { type: Number, required: true },
      month: { type: Number },
      day: { type: Number },
      hour: { type: Number },
      minute: { type: Number }
    },
    end_date: {
      year: { type: Number },
      month: { type: Number },
      day: { type: Number },
      hour: { type: Number },
      minute: { type: Number }
    }
  }
});
```

And what I would like to do is, when performing a simple query to find all documents, return all the documents sorted by ascending order of the object `start_date`, i.e, the object itself represents a date and I would like to return all documents by ascending dates. Is it possible to do something like this? If yes, how?

If not possible, I suppose I could have an additional field of type `Date` and then use this field for sorting, right? Although I may not have the complete object (year, month, day, hours and minutes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try it with multiple sort fields

```
Post.find({}).sort({'data.start_date.year': 1,
                    'data.start_date.month': 1,
                    'data.start_date.day': 1,
                    'data.start_date.hour': 1,
                    'data.start_date.minute': 1
                  }).exec(function(err, results){})
```

In this way, it is better to build [index](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/) for it,

```
postSchema.index({'data.start_date.year': 1,
                        'data.start_date.month': 1,
                        'data.start_date.day': 1,
                        'data.start_date.hour': 1,
                        'data.start_date.minute': 1});
```

However, it could be better just store the field `start_date` as one `Date()` type.

Comment: Awesome :-) index for sorting documents.

Comment: For the requirements and purposes of my application, it is better to have the field `start_date` as an object (as is). However, this seems to work! Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.find({})
    .sort({'data.start_date.year': 1,
           'data.start_date.month': 1,
           'data.start_date.day': 1,
           'data.start_date.hour': 1,
           'data.start_date.minute': 1
          })
     .exec(function(err, result){

     });
```

Comment: I would recommend adding an explanation of the code you've posted to improve the quality of your answer